# Pass character into formula

Tags: r

I'm making an aggregation:

```
iris$group <- sample(1:2, 150, T)
aggregate(Sepal.Length ~ Species + group , data = iris, FUN = function(x) c(m = mean(x), n = length(x)))
```

Now I want to replace `group` with the variable: `variable = "group"` and aggregation should do the same as above:

```
iris$group <- sample(1:2, 150, T)    
variable = "group"
aggregate(Sepal.Length ~ Species + variable , data = iris, FUN = function(x) c(m = mean(x), n = length(x)))
```

but then error occurs. I tried with `eval` and it didn't help.

Comment: You need `aggregate(formula(paste("Sepal.Length ~ Species +", variable)), data = iris, FUN = function(x) c(m = mean(x), n = length(x)))`

Comment: @akrun this will do interesting stuff if `variable = "factor(Sepal.Width)"` or the like.

Comment: It seems to be evaluating correctly.  Only thing is that in the formula, the column name will be changed to `factor(Sepal.Width)`

Comment: @akrun Yes, but it shouldn't - `factor(Sepal.Width)` is not a column of iris. `variable` isn't `expression_to_be_evaluated_if_you_do_something_funny`. Plus, if you add a variable named `factor(Sepal.Width)` for some reason, it won't work as expected - the correct formula would be Sepal.Length ~ Species + `factor(Sepal.Width)` (single backticks enclosing the term)

Comment: @AlexR  Anyway, I didn't post that as a solution and it was just a comment

Answer (score 5):

Use `` as.formula(sprintf("Sepal.Length ~ Species + `%s`", variable)) `` to get a formula with one term replaced. 
Care must be taken in the input of variable to be a length-1 character vector. Backticks in the string template prevent evaluation of expressions like `variable = "factor(Sepal.Width)"` and can be omitted if that is desired to work.

If it is also okay to have `variable = ~...` as an argument, you can use `modelr::add_predictors(Sepal.Length ~ Species, variable)` to combine the formulas.